# Fill out woocommerce checkout fields with user meta data

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, checkout

When woocommerce checkout page loads, some fields (like first_name, last_name, state) are prefilled.

But other fields (phone, city, postcode) are empty.

All of checkout fields' data are available in user meta data.

How can I fill checkout field's with user meta data?
I tried some codes like this by adding it to my functions.php file.

Have any advice?
Regards,

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'itdoc_remove_fields', 9999 );


function itdoc_remove_fields( $woo_checkout_fields_array ) {
    
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $dealer_phone= get_user_meta($user->ID, 'phone' , true);
    $dealer_city= get_user_meta($user->ID, 'dealer_city' , true);
    $dealer_state= get_user_meta($user->ID, 'postcode' , true);
    print($dealer_phone);

    $woo_checkout_fields_array['billing']['billing_phone']['default'] = $dealer_phone ;
    $woo_checkout_fields_array['billing']['billing_city']['default'] = $dealer_city;
    $woo_checkout_fields_array['billing']['billing_postcode']['default'] = $dealer_postcode;
    var_dump($woo_checkout_fields_array);


    return $woo_checkout_fields_array;
}
```

// This does not any effect on checkout fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the right hook for that, try the following instead:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_get_value', 'autofill_some_checkout_fields', 10, 2 );
function autofill_some_checkout_fields( $value, $input ) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    
    if( $input === 'billing_phone' && empty($value) && isset($user->phone) ) {
        $value = $user->phone;
    }
    
    if( $input === 'billing_city' && empty($value) && isset($user->dealer_city) ) {
        $value = $user->dealer_city;
    }
    
    if( $input === 'billing_postcode' && empty($value) && isset($user->postcode)  ) {
        $value = $user->postcode;
    }
    return $value;
}
```

It should work.

Comment: hello, i tried the solution above but it did not work. but instead of billing_phone, i used the other 'phone' field on the additional section of my checkout page. i have 4 sections: billing details, shipping details, additional details, contact details(added section). inside contact details are fields like email, phone, first_name and last_name. tried your solution by replacing the billing fields with my fields but won't work. anything i miss?

Comment: @TsukimotoMitsumasa Your "contact details" section fields need to be saved as custom **user** metadata when an order is placed, to be able to use that custom user field values in my answer code…